# JQuery Slideup/Slidedown a div only after previous div animation or after delay

Tags: jquery, css

Currently I have a JQuery script in place http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zzj7E/5/ which handles the requirement that when i hover on a particular div, a hidden div slides down. This happens on every div i hover on.

However you will notice that if one hovers his mouse quickly over the set of divs, it leaves several divs sliding down at once. Actually i dont want this.

What i want is that unless the previous div hasnt fully slided up the other div wont slide down even if hovered on. Or if possible show the div slide down effect only if the user has the mouse hover it for above 1.5 secs.

Is this possible to implemented in jQuery? Can someone help?

**EDIT:**
Had to use .live() to add the effect to dynamically added elements. COuld nt use hover with live() as its proving cumbersome. Below is the code am using

```
 $(".altbgcolor").live('mouseenter', function() {
              //hover code
              $(this)
                    .addClass('altbgcolor-active')
                    .find(".sharedp")
                    .slideDown('slow');
            }).live('mouseleave', function() {
              //stopped hovering code
              $(this)
                    .removeClass('altbgcolor-active')
                    .find(".sharedp")
                    .slideUp('slow');
            });
```

How to integrate the effect in this mouseenter and mouseleave events?

Comment: sure everything is possible. But its not very clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/zzj7E/27/

```
$(".altbgcolor").hover(function() {
    var el= $(this);
    el.addClass('altbgcolor-active');
    el.data('hover', setTimeout(function()
        {
            if (el.hasClass('altbgcolor-active'))
            {
                el.find(".sharedp").slideDown('normal');
            }
        }, 1500)
    );

},function () {
    var el= $(this);
    clearTimeout(el.data('hover'));
    el.removeClass('altbgcolor-active')
        .find(".sharedp")
        .slideUp('normal');
});
```

EDIT: if using mouseover and mouseout events instead of hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/zzj7E/30/

```
$(".altbgcolor").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var el= $(this);
        el.addClass('altbgcolor-active');
        el.data('hover', setTimeout(function()
            {
                if (el.hasClass('altbgcolor-active'))
                {
                    el.find(".sharedp").slideDown('normal');
                }
            }, 1500)
        );      
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var el= $(this);
        clearTimeout(el.data('hover'));
        el.removeClass('altbgcolor-active')
            .find(".sharedp")
            .slideUp('normal');
    }
});
```

Comment: you should clear the timeout somewhere, now you have the same problem but delayed by 1.5 seconds

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the solution. It worked perfectly. But however now I have changed for using "hover" to "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" as i needed to use .live() function. Any idea how to achieve the above effect when "hover" is not used? :(

Comment: @Sunny D'Souza - updated my answer to show how you can achieve the same by using `live` instead of `hover`.

Comment: @RoccoC5 sorry for the late response, RoccoC5, but I used the above solution. For some unknown reason, it doesnt seem to be working. COuld you please check it out. I have used it on my site here http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com

Comment: Please RoccoC5...could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want but i think you are looking for [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

there is your updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zzj7E/18/